# swift UISearchControllerで検索中にタブバーで画面遷移した場合の動作について

Tags: swift, xcode

UISearchControllerを利用し検索バーを表示させています。

検索バーからtable viewの検索結果を表示後、UITabBarControllerのタブバーで画面遷移し、
その後、元の検索画面に戻ると検索バーのみが表示され画面が真っ暗になってしまいます。

・画面A（検索結果表示）
・画面B（その他画面）

画面A（検索結果表示）→　画面B　→　画面A（画面真っ暗）
※画面遷移はタブバーで実施

なお、画面Aの「viewWillAppear」でreloadDataなどを書いてみたのですが、
検索結果を表示している時に画面遷移を行うとviewWillAppear(viewWillDisappearも)
が実行されないようです。
検索していない状態の時はviewWillAppearが実行されます。

改善策を教えていただけますでしょうか。

[image: 画面遷移前の検索結果表示中の画面]
[image: 画面B→画面A実施後]

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

遷移前のviewDidLoadに↓を追加したら正常になりました。
definesPresentationContext = true